# NDK ambiguous 'log' error with c++_static

Tags: android, c++11, gradle, android-ndk, libc++

I'am building my cpp library using CMake and gradle on Android with Android Studio 2.2.3.
I'am using c++_static as STL but I always obtain these errors:

```
error: reference to 'log' is ambiguous log(_A1 __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return log((double)__lcpp_x);}

note: candidate found by name lookup is 'log' log(_A1 __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return log((double)__lcpp_x);}
note: candidate found by name lookup is 'log' inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY long double log(long double __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return logl(__lcpp_x);}
note: candidate found by name lookup is 'log' inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY float       log(float __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT       {return logf(__lcpp_x);}
note: candidate found by name lookup is 'log' double  log(double);
```

for header: android-ndk-r13b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/math.h .

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Could you include an example? My trivial test cases work fine.

Comment: @AlexCohn It is present into a template definition into android-ndk-r13b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/math.h.

Comment: template <class _A1>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<_A1>::value, double>::type
log(_A1 __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return log((double)__lcpp_x);}

Comment: cool, I understand that **_A1** is a template parameter. What is it in your case? Or maybe it will be easier for you to show how you use the **log()** function in your code. If you have something like, `int k=5; double lk = log(k);` you may resolve the problem as `int k=5; double lk = log((double)k);`

Comment: Thank you, I solved my problem!